# How to constrain flex container's height to be the same height as its parent?

Tags: css, flexbox

Component library has a modal component with a scrollable content section to accomodate potentially long content that users can put:

```css
.modal {
  position: fixed;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  width: 300px;
  max-height: 80vh;
  outline: 4px solid;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.header {
  background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.2);
  padding-block: 8px;
}

.content {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  min-height: 0;
}

.inner-content {
  height: 100%;
  overflow-y: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="modal">
  <div class="header">Header</div>
  <div class="content">
    <div class="inner-content">
      Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old. Richard McClintock, a Latin professor at Hampden-Sydney College in Virginia, looked up
      one of the more obscure Latin words, consectetur, from a Lorem Ipsum passage, and going through the cites of the word in classical literature, discovered the undoubtable source. Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text.
      It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old. Richard McClintock, a Latin professor at Hampden-Sydney College in Virginia, looked up one of the more obscure Latin words, consectetur, from a Lorem
      Ipsum passage, and going through the cites of the word in classical literature, discovered the undoubtable source. Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC,
      making it over 2000 years old. Richard McClintock, a Latin professor at Hampden-Sydney College in Virginia, looked up one of the more obscure Latin words, consectetur, from a Lorem Ipsum passage, and going through the cites of the word in classical
      literature, discovered the undoubtable source. Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old. Richard McClintock, a Latin professor
      at Hampden-Sydney College in Virginia, looked up one of the more obscure Latin words, consectetur, from a Lorem Ipsum passage, and going through the cites of the word in classical literature, discovered the undoubtable source. Contrary to popular
      belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old. Richard McClintock, a Latin professor at Hampden-Sydney College in Virginia, looked up one of the more
      obscure Latin words, consectetur, from a Lorem Ipsum passage, and going through the cites of the word in classical literature, discovered the undoubtable source. Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in
      a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old. Richard McClintock, a Latin professor at Hampden-Sydney College in Virginia, looked up one of the more obscure Latin words, consectetur, from a Lorem Ipsum passage,
      and going through the cites of the word in classical literature, discovered the undoubtable source. </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

User decides to place a **content header** and a **content main** section inside the modal. Since their content main is quite long, they want the **content main** itself to be scrollable, while the **content header** should always be visible at the top of modal's content.

```css
.modal {
  position: fixed;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  width: 300px;
  max-height: 80vh;
  outline: 4px solid;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.header {
  background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.2);
  padding-block: 8px;
}

.content {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  min-height: 0;
}

.inner-content {
  height: 100%;
  overflow-y: auto;
}

.content-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.content-header {
  flex-shrink: 0;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 255, 0.2);
  padding-block: 20px;
}

.content-main {
  overflow-y: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="modal">
  <div class="header">Header</div>
  <div class="content">
    <div class="inner-content">
      <div class="content-container">
        <div class="content-header">
          Main header
        </div>
        <div class="content-main">
          Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old. Richard McClintock, a Latin professor at Hampden-Sydney College in Virginia, looked up
          one of the more obscure Latin words, consectetur, from a Lorem Ipsum passage, and going through the cites of the word in classical literature, discovered the undoubtable source. Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text.
          It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old. Richard McClintock, a Latin professor at Hampden-Sydney College in Virginia, looked up one of the more obscure Latin words, consectetur, from a
          Lorem Ipsum passage, and going through the cites of the word in classical literature, discovered the undoubtable source. Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature
          from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old. Richard McClintock, a Latin professor at Hampden-Sydney College in Virginia, looked up one of the more obscure Latin words, consectetur, from a Lorem Ipsum passage, and going through the cites of the
          word in classical literature, discovered the undoubtable source. Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old. Richard McClintock,
          a Latin professor at Hampden-Sydney College in Virginia, looked up one of the more obscure Latin words, consectetur, from a Lorem Ipsum passage, and going through the cites of the word in classical literature, discovered the undoubtable source.
          Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old. Richard McClintock, a Latin professor at Hampden-Sydney College in Virginia,
          looked up one of the more obscure Latin words, consectetur, from a Lorem Ipsum passage, and going through the cites of the word in classical literature, discovered the undoubtable source. Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply
          random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old. Richard McClintock, a Latin professor at Hampden-Sydney College in Virginia, looked up one of the more obscure Latin words, consectetur,
          from a Lorem Ipsum passage, and going through the cites of the word in classical literature, discovered the undoubtable source. Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature
          from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old. Richard McClintock, a Latin professor at Hampden-Sydney College in Virginia, looked up one of the more obscure Latin words, consectetur, from a Lorem Ipsum passage, and going through the cites of the
          word in classical literature, discovered the undoubtable source. Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old. Richard McClintock,
          a Latin professor at Hampden-Sydney College in Virginia, looked up one of the more obscure Latin words, consectetur, from a Lorem Ipsum passage, and going through the cites of the word in classical literature, discovered the undoubtable source.
          Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old. Richard McClintock, a Latin professor at Hampden-Sydney College in Virginia,
          looked up one of the more obscure Latin words, consectetur, from a Lorem Ipsum passage, and going through the cites of the word in classical literature, discovered the undoubtable source. Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply
          random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old. Richard McClintock, a Latin professor at Hampden-Sydney College in Virginia, looked up one of the more obscure Latin words, consectetur,
          from a Lorem Ipsum passage, and going through the cites of the word in classical literature, discovered the undoubtable source. Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature
          from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old. Richard McClintock, a Latin professor at Hampden-Sydney College in Virginia, looked up one of the more obscure Latin words, consectetur, from a Lorem Ipsum passage, and going through the cites of the
          word in classical literature, discovered the undoubtable source. Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old. Richard McClintock,
          a Latin professor at Hampden-Sydney College in Virginia, looked up one of the more obscure Latin words, consectetur, from a Lorem Ipsum passage, and going through the cites of the word in classical literature, discovered the undoubtable source.
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

As you can see in this failed attempt, the modal's content is still scrollable, while the **content main** is not.

How could I make the **content main** scrollable instead, and have **content header** to  always be visible at the top of modal's content. Modal's content **should not** be scrollable.

I feel that I need to constrain the `content-container` to be the same height as its parent, but I'm not sure how.

Note that I don't have control over the modal component itself. I can only control the HTML and CSS inside `inner-content`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the comments for the code update. You were close:

```css
.modal {
  position: fixed;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  width: 300px;
  max-height: 80vh;
  outline: 4px solid;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.header {
  background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.2);
  padding-block: 8px;
}

.content {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  min-height: 0;
}

.inner-content {
  /* height: 100%;
  overflow-y: auto; Removed */
  min-height: 0; /* added */
  display: flex; /* make this a flex container to get the stretch alignment */
}

.content-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.content-header {
  flex-shrink: 0;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 255, 0.2);
  padding-block: 20px;
}

.content-main {
  overflow-y: auto;
  flex: 1; /* fill all the same minus the one of content-header */
}
```

```html
<div class="modal">
  <div class="header">Header</div>
  <div class="content">
    <div class="inner-content">
      <div class="content-container">
        <div class="content-header">
          Main header
        </div>
        <div class="content-main">
          Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old. Richard McClintock, a Latin professor at Hampden-Sydney College in Virginia, looked up
          one of the more obscure Latin words, consectetur, from a Lorem Ipsum passage, and going through the cites of the word in classical literature, discovered the undoubtable source. Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text.
          It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old. Richard McClintock, a Latin professor at Hampden-Sydney College in Virginia, looked up one of the more obscure Latin words, consectetur, from a
          Lorem Ipsum passage, and going through the cites of the word in classical literature, discovered the undoubtable source. Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature
          from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old. Richard McClintock, a Latin professor at Hampden-Sydney College in Virginia, looked up one of the more obscure Latin words, consectetur, from a Lorem Ipsum passage, and going through the cites of the
          word in classical literature, discovered the undoubtable source. Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old. Richard McClintock,
          a Latin professor at Hampden-Sydney College in Virginia, looked up one of the more obscure Latin words, consectetur, from a Lorem Ipsum passage, and going through the cites of the word in classical literature, discovered the undoubtable source.
          Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old. Richard McClintock, a Latin professor at Hampden-Sydney College in Virginia,
          looked up one of the more obscure Latin words, consectetur, from a Lorem Ipsum passage, and going through the cites of the word in classical literature, discovered the undoubtable source. Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply
          random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old. Richard McClintock, a Latin professor at Hampden-Sydney College in Virginia, looked up one of the more obscure Latin words, consectetur,
          from a Lorem Ipsum passage, and going through the cites of the word in classical literature, discovered the undoubtable source. Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature
          from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old. Richard McClintock, a Latin professor at Hampden-Sydney College in Virginia, looked up one of the more obscure Latin words, consectetur, from a Lorem Ipsum passage, and going through the cites of the
          word in classical literature, discovered the undoubtable source. Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old. Richard McClintock,
          a Latin professor at Hampden-Sydney College in Virginia, looked up one of the more obscure Latin words, consectetur, from a Lorem Ipsum passage, and going through the cites of the word in classical literature, discovered the undoubtable source.
          Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old. Richard McClintock, a Latin professor at Hampden-Sydney College in Virginia,
          looked up one of the more obscure Latin words, consectetur, from a Lorem Ipsum passage, and going through the cites of the word in classical literature, discovered the undoubtable source. Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply
          random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old. Richard McClintock, a Latin professor at Hampden-Sydney College in Virginia, looked up one of the more obscure Latin words, consectetur,
          from a Lorem Ipsum passage, and going through the cites of the word in classical literature, discovered the undoubtable source. Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature
          from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old. Richard McClintock, a Latin professor at Hampden-Sydney College in Virginia, looked up one of the more obscure Latin words, consectetur, from a Lorem Ipsum passage, and going through the cites of the
          word in classical literature, discovered the undoubtable source. Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old. Richard McClintock,
          a Latin professor at Hampden-Sydney College in Virginia, looked up one of the more obscure Latin words, consectetur, from a Lorem Ipsum passage, and going through the cites of the word in classical literature, discovered the undoubtable source.
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: A couple of questions regarding your proposal: (1) Removing `overflow-y: auto` from `inner-content` means that if someone puts a very long text inside it (instead of the `content-container`), this text will overflow modal's content and won't be scrollable. By default, I'd like to keep modal's content scrollable when people put long content inside the modal. Any reason not to keep the `overflow-y: auto` on `inner-content`? (2) I can't see the effect of adding `flex: 1` on `content-main`. What's wrong if it's not there?

Comment: (3) When `content-main` has a very short text, how could I make `content-header` and `content-main` to span the full modal's width?

Comment: @MishaMoroshko (1) you can keep overflow: auto, I simply considered the fact that you want content-main to be scrollable so it's not needed on its parent (2) flex:1 is useful to make sure the content span all the area but if you have a lot of content it won't do anything. even without a lot of content you may not notice its effect unless you add a background or border (3) flex:1 or width:100% to content-container

Comment: (3) I wouldn't want to pass the responsibility of setting `flex: 1` or `width: 100%` to the user of the modal. I'd like the content to span full width by default. That's why I originally had the default `display: block` on `inner-content` rather than `display: flex` like you're suggesting. Any ideas?

Comment: @MishaMoroshko it's not the responsibility of the user, it's part of the configuration. you can add it all the time to make it by default full width whatever the content. It's not a solution that depend on the content. And I need that display: flex otherwise I will have to use a more complex CSS setting

Comment: Oh, I see. You're suggesting that `content-container` is part of the modal component itself. Quite a few divs are needed to achieve the desired behaviour here, but I guess it works! Thank you very much for your help!!

Answer (score 1):

**solution 1**
You need to set fixed height (not %) on .content-main.
remove .content-container property.

```
.content-main{
 overflow-y: auto;
 height: 68vh;
}
```

**solution 2**
you can set `position:sticky` with `top:0` on .content-header